# How to make marker for latlng from database?

Tags: javascript, java, api, google-maps, dictionary

how to make marker for this kind of latlng? (-25.274398, 133.77513599999997).

I did everything that I've learned but I guess I need help.

Comment: Can you write what you actually tried?

Comment: <script>
    function initMap() {
    var latlng = (-25.274398, 133.77513599999997).
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: uluru
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: ullatlngru,
      map: map,
    });
   }
  </script>

Answer (score 1):

I think you give the latLng then create a marker. Create a function parameter with latLng.

```
    <div id='mapId' style='width:500px; height:400px;'></div>
    var lat=-25.274398;
    var long = 133.775;
    //Create Map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapId'), {
        zoom: 1,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.274398, 133.775),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    function(lat, Lng)
    {
        var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, Lng), //-25.274398, 133.77513599999997
            draggable: true
        });
    }
```

Define different long and lat. You can't give string latLng.

Your question solve this [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/egvrcn/Lov7bg7u/2/)

Comment: Did you create the map?

Comment: yes I did.<script>
    function initMap() {
    var latlng = (-25.274398, 133.77513599999997).
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: uluru
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: ullatlngru,
      map: map,
    });
   }
  </script>

Comment: I create new fiddle in my answer.

Comment: but I have a lot of lat and lng in my database so I made it latlng inorder to plot/create the specific marker but it doesnt work

Comment: You can split your data.

Comment: yes I can but it is possible to put marker to the specific lat,lng when I have a lot of lats and lngs?

Comment: You can create a separator function for latlng.

Comment: I have this in my db (-25.274398, 133.77513599999997) can you teach me how to separate this?

Comment: var db = "-25.274398, 133.77513599999997";
var array = db.split(',');
//lat => array[0]  long => array[1]

Comment: thanks, how do I create marker for three latlng? like                      (3.16376, 101.72963000000004)
(40.46366700000001, -3.7492200000000366)
(-25.274398, 133.77513599999997)  I put these three inside <input type='text' id='placelatlng' value='$result->latlng'>

Answer (score 0):

if u have lat and lng then u have to do this.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.274398, 133.77513599999997),
      zoom: 17,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="width:500px; height:500px;"></div>
```